# How to reference an item numbered with prefix, without printing the prefix itself?

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

Suppose I defined a list template, with format `Table %1.`, so it will produce items

```
Table 1.
Table 2.
Table 3.
```

...and so on.

Now I want to reference one such item in text (e.g. "a curious reader can look at table `3` and `5`").

Unfortunately, however I try, I cannot succeed referencing *only the number*. I always get something like "a curious reader can look at table `Table 3.` and `Table 5.`"

I know, that I can use custom sequence field in place of List template, like this `SEQ TableSeq \* ARABIC` and reference the custom sequence `TableSeq`. But then, I'd loose the sugar of automatic prefixing the actual numbered item (not it's reference) with the word `Table`.

Or maybe I'm wrong, and there is some arcane way to define the equivalent to the `SEQ` field, that will actually print the whole `Table 1.` when defined, and only `1` when referenced?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible using the built-in numbering feature.

In this particular case, you might be able to get around the problem by inserting the REF field and nesting it as follows

```
{ ={ SET x { REF "_Ref378240752" \r } }x }
```

but then you lose "sugar" in other ways.

(i.e. where you use the appropriate bookmark name in your REF field, and all the {} are the special field code brace pairs that you can insert in Windows Word using ctrl-F9). I don't think you can simplify this using the apprarently equivalents...

```
{ ={ REF "_Ref378240752" \r } }
```

or

```
{ ={ QUOTE { REF "_Ref378240752" \r } } }
```

Further, because Word can evaluate field codes inconsistently when printing, depending on whether update field codes is switched on or off, you may need to use a different bookmark name for each reference. I haven't checked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually simple, once I looked (again) at [the definition of the `REF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-ref-field-HP005186139.aspx).

There is a switch `\t` specifically for this purpose. So the recipe is this:

1. Define the chart/table numbering scheme with custom format = "Table %1." or similar.
2. Put the bookmark on the item you wish to reference.
3. When writing the reference, use the `REF` field with `\r \t \h` arguments, like this:

> In the tables `{REF tbl_tab1 \r \t \h}` and `{REF tbl_tab5 \r \t \h}` we
>   can see very interesting data